# How can I get this JSONP call to return a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, return, jsonp

The purpose of the following functions are to access a script on Yahoo's servers and lookup a live currency conversion rate which will later be used to process a customer's purchases.

I'm able to access the rates in the JavaScript alert but I can't seem to return them to the Jquery method which originally called the `getRate()` function.

I've tried a standard `return rate;` at the end of the `parseExchangeRate()` function, which doesn't work. I've also tried setting `rate` as a global variable within `parseExchangeRate()` but that doesn't work either.

```
function getRate(from, to) {

    var script = document.createElement('script');

    script.setAttribute('src', "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D"+from+to+"%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json&callback=parseExchangeRate");
    document.body.appendChild(script);

}

function parseExchangeRate(data) {

    var name = data.query.results.row.name;
    rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);

    alert("Exchange rate " + name + " is " + rate);

}

$(function() {

    getRate('USD', 'PHP');
    xRatePHP = rate;

    /* Do stuff with rate */

});
```

Firebug informs me the `rate` is undefined when I try to access it in Jquery function.

The other thing I tried was setting the last parameter of the http request to `callback=rate=parseExchangeRate` which (not surprisingly) didn't work either.

**UPDATE**

@Relfor solved the original problem, which was that `rate` was not properly declared as a global variable in the global scope. I fixed that and then found a further issue which some have also identified below, which is that after `getRate()` is called (which can take about 2000ms to update the variable `rate`), the script moves on immediately without waiting for `rate` to be updated and uses rate regardless of whether it's ready.

I tried was attempting to use `window.setInterval` to create a delay to solve this, when it came to my attention that their was still activity in the thread even though I'd already accepted @Relfor's answer, so I'd prefer to bring it back here so that when we have this working, others can benefit from the solutions.

There is one final *(I hope - final!)* problem and that is that in order simplify the original question for posting, I ommitted to disclose that I'm actually trying to get two rates from Yahoo! (which possibly a few more planned) and therefore, I'm calling `getRate()` in a loop as follows:

```
function getRate(from, to) {

    var script = document.createElement('script');

    script.setAttribute('src', "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D"+from+to+"%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json&callback=parseExchangeRate");
    document.body.appendChild(script);

}

function parseExchangeRate(data) {

    var name = data.query.results.row.name;
    rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);

}

var rate = 1.00;
var timer;
var q;
var xRatePHP, xRateGBP;
$(function() {

    function getTheRates() {

        var rateArr = new Array('PHP','GBP');

        for (var x=0; x < rateArr.length; x++) {
            getRate('USD', rateArr[x]);

            q = 0;
            timer = window.setInterval(function(){manageTimer(rateArr[x])},100);

        }
    }

    function manageTimer(c) {

        if (rate != 1) {

            window.clearInterval(timer);

            /* Note that 'c' is undefined according to 'alert' below,
             * so this next line is not working correctly.
             */
            eval("xRate"+c+" = rate;"); 


            alert(c + " = " + rate); // displays 'undefined 43.543'

            rate = 1.00;

        }

        q++;

        if (q > 30 ) {

            window.clearInterval(timer);

            // added below because above isn't working (but neither does this!)
            timer = '';
            alert(c+' timeout'); // 'c' is undefined according to alert ???
            q = 0;

        }

    }

    getTheRates();

    /* Do stuff with the rates */

});
```

It was suggested that I move `/* Do stuff with the rates */` to inside the function `parseExchangeRate()` but not sure whether that advice would still stand given my revelations about calling `getRate()` in a loop?

**UPDATE 3 (replaced update 2)**

I have created a JSbin here: http://jsbin.com/udikas/3/edit with the above which apart from these two issues appears to be working:

1) The timeout mechanism appears not to be working.

2) On line 33 this line `alert('start timer (' + x +')');` without which, the timer doesn't seem to start! I have no idea why, but I can't leave that line in.

Comment: You don't assign it a value before it's used. Since this is a non-local variable it should be a ReferenceError. However, it appears that there is *missing context* and, perhaps `parseExchangeRate` is the callback for an AJAX call. In which case, keep this in mind: *the callback probably happens asynchronously*.

Comment: Would it not be better to discard the "callback" parameter of the URL and simply use an AJAX request, which returns the JSON that you can then pass into whatever function you need.

Comment: @Paul I don't assign a value before `rate` is used but I just tried that now and it made no difference. There is no AJAX involved in this.

Comment: @mibbler does AJAX work cross-domain? I didn't think it does.

Comment: I needed to initialize the global variable in the Jquery method prior to calling the functions, not from inside one, which is what I tried. @Paul you were right but I needed the help of Relfor below to figure out where to put it.

Comment: It's JSONP when call getRate and the next line is executed `xRatePHP=rate` the function `parseExchangeRate` hasn't been executed yest due to the asynchronous nature of JSONP.

Comment: @PeterSnow I think you can do cross-domain ajax using jQuery, but I'm not 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the variable `rate` has not been defined

```
$(function() {

    getRate('USD', 'PHP');
    xRatePHP = rate;

    /* Do stuff with rate */

});
```

after studying your code it seems that rate is defined in the `parseExchange(data)` function as

```
function parseExchangeRate(data) {

    var name = data.query.results.row.name;
    rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);

    alert("Exchange rate " + name + " is " + rate);

}
```

if you want rate to be accessible from the function namespaces without declaring them from within then the rates would have to specified in the global namespace, which is outside any of the functions or loops.

**Edit**: The namespace problem has been solved and the answer I've given has been accepted, however I would like to add details about the code you are handling here. It has been taken from the gist here: https://gist.github.com/henrik/265014

### We are dealing with JSONP here

the reason why `parseExchangeRate` exists and the context of it can seem mysterious at first glance, albeit its existence is the primary connection between your JSONP request and the data returned by the response.

If you take a closer look at the request:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?
q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2F
download.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2F
quotes%3Fs%3DUSDPHP%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20
columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json&callback=parseExchangeRate
```

(I broke the link up into many lines to make it easier to read)
Carefully look at the last segment of the url: `callback=parseExchangeRate`
This here is the connection, when the JSONP request is complete parseExchangeRate will be called.

#### So then why did it not work?

Let me display the code once again:

```
$(function() {

    getRate('USD', 'PHP');
    xRatePHP = rate;

    /* Do stuff with rate */

});
```

We should break this up:

- `getRate('USD', 'PHP')` does the job of loading the JSONP with the respective currency types of 'USD' and 'PHP'
- `xRatePHP = rate` assigns the right hand side which is `rate` to `xRatePHP`. **But this line gave us a problem! our console pal told us that `rate` is undefined!**

**The truth:** mr.console did not lie, `rate` is actually undefined, **however** mr.console **without any further commands given by you** a few moments later if asked again would reply that `rate` is actually defined. Is this magic?

What is actually happening is that between the time you go from this line

```
getRate('USD', 'PHP');
```

to

```
xRatePHP = rate;
```

the JSONP response from mr.yahoo hasn't yet come back, which is why when `xRatePHP = rate` is issued `rate` seems to be undefined.

**Hard Code Solution**
Let us hard code a duration for our code to wait before using `rate` so that we know that mr.yahoo responded, `setTimeout` will helps us here:

```
getRate('USD', 'PHP');
setTimeout(function(){alert(rate)}, 2000);
```

and everything works now! check the demo at: http://jsbin.com/udikas/1/edit

**Soft Code**
did you ever consider the case where mr.yahoo takes more than 2000 ms to respond? or maybe even lesser than that? (yahoo is pretty fast!) let us instead take a different approach, this will let us use `rate` the **exact moment** we calculate it with `parseExchangeRate`

for this we will have to add a callback from `parseExchangeRate`:

```
function parseExchangeRate(data) {

    var name = data.query.results.row.name;
    rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);

    alert("Exchange rate " + name + " is " + rate);

}
```

to

```
function parseExchangeRate(data) {

    var name = data.query.results.row.name;
    rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);

    alert("Exchange rate " + name + " is " + rate);
    gotTheRate(rate)

}
```

and then change

```
$(function() {

    getRate('USD', 'PHP');
    alert(rate)

});
```

to

```
function gotTheRate(rate){
    alert(rate);
  }

$(function() {

    getRate('USD', 'PHP');
      
});
```

a demo of this can be found at http://jsbin.com/udikas/2/edit

#### Multiple Callbacks (in response to question update)

Remember hard coding `setTimeouts` isn't fun, so let us remove that, `manageTimer`, `q`, and other such elements from your code, instead we can have:

```
function getRate(from, to) {

    var script = document.createElement('script');

    script.setAttribute('src', "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D"+from+to+"%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json&callback=parseExchangeRate");
    document.body.appendChild(script);

}

function parseExchangeRate(data) {

    var name = data.query.results.row.name;
  
    rateDict[name.match(/USD to ([\w]*)/)[1]] = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);
    total_responses++;
  if (total_responses === rateArr.length){
    for (var k in rateDict){
        alert("USD to " + k + " is " + rateDict[k]);
    }
  }
}

var rate = 1.00;
var timer;
var q;
var rateArr = new Array('PHP','GBP')
var total_responses = 0;
var rateDict = {};

$(function() {

    function getTheRates() {


        for (var x=0; x < rateArr.length; x++) {

            getRate('USD', rateArr[x]);

        }
    }

    getTheRates();
  

});
```

http://jsbin.com/udikas/4/edit

-Relfor

Comment: OP is using JSONP, `getRate` adds javascript to the page from Yahoo and when done calls the function `parseExchangeRate` since the OP wants to access the `rate` variable directly after calling `getRate` he get's an error. This is because the script hasn't loaded yet and the callback `parseExchangeRate` hasn't been called back yet. The OP needs to do something with `rate` in the `parseExchangeRate` function.

Comment: precisely, the code is incomplete, `rate` needs to exist in the namespace before it is used, which in this case its not. after the JSONP load i assume the `rate` would be calculated by calling `parseExchangeRate` and thus available for `xRatePHP` or any other variable to be assigned `rate`.

Comment: Asynchronous execution. XratePHP is set to the value of rate right after calling `getRate` but getRate hasn't called parseExchangeRate yet. Defining rate will not help XratePHP being set with a bogus value because parseExchangeRate hasn't been called yet to set it with the actual value returned from Yahoo.

Comment: +1 for your continued involvement. I've updated my post with additional / updated information. Thanks @Relfor.

Comment: Just updated my original post again with more information about what's happening. Will now take a closer look at how I might integrate your suggestions above with my multiple rates. Thanks for the jsbin by the way - nice touch.

Comment: That's a vast improvement on my way. The only problem is that I'm tryig to gain access to `rateDict()` by adding a line below the call to getTheRates() as follows: `alert("Final rate PHP = "+  rateDict['PHP']);` but it says it's undefined. The same line works within the scope of `parseExchangeRate()`.

Comment: I've just attempted to move the `/* Do stuff with rates */` into the end of `parseExchangeRate()` but then it stopped working and Firebug said 'calculateCost is not defined'. `calculateCost` is a function contained in the code I moved in. I have created a new jsbin with the entire page html, CSS and JavaScript complete as seeing the whole picture I'm sure will help. It's here http://jsbin.com/oserok/1/edit .

Answer (score 1):

You should re order your code flow:

```
function getRate(from, to) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D"+from+to+"%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json&callback=parseExchangeRate");
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
function parseExchangeRate(data) {
    var name = data.query.results.row.name;
    var rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);
    alert("Exchange rate " + name + " is " + rate);
    xRatePHP = rate;
    /* Do stuff with rate */
}
$(function() {
    getRate('USD', 'PHP');
    // rate is not yet available here, so don't do anything with it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put:

```
var rate = 0;
```

on top of your code. This will fix the error.
Then you have to consider that if you get 0 maybe you are reading the variable at the wrong time, before it gets populated.