# JSONP callback out of order

Tags: javascript, json, callback, jsonp

I apologise if this is a repeated question. I have done my research but I am still unable to come up with an answer:

I am writing a small JSONP API. The desired outcome:

1. The programmer creates an instance of the JSON class.

   ```
   var json = new jsonpRequest (

   "http://url.to.web_service",

   searchParam //passed in as an associative array

   );
   ```
2. The programmer then declares `var myJSON = jsonpRequest.getJsonP()`

This will return the JSONP into the myJSON variable to be processed.

The API successfully takes in the parameters when the instance of the class is constructed, generates a link to the services w/ the desired parameters and injects it into the DOM via script tags using this function:

```
jsonpRequest.prototype.fetchJsonp = function(){

    var request = that.getRequest();

     //creates a script element

     var jsonpCall = document.createElement('script');

     //gets jsonp request
     jsonpCall.src = request;

     //adds script to DOM, which goes on to request the JSONP from the service.
     document.head.appendChild(jsonpCall);


};
```

**EDIT:** For the sake of clarity: this definitely does return the data set that is requested.

The function I am using as my callback is:

```
jsonpRequest.prototype.processCallback = function(data){

    alert(data);
    that.setListOfResults(data);

};
```

It is called in the link as: `&callback=jsonpRequest.prototype.processCallback`

The `processCallback` function takes in the data from the request and stores it in a variable within the class using the `setListOfResults` function.

After the data has been stored I would like to return the data from the request to the `myJSON` variable. This is the `getJsonp` function that the programmer invokes in step 2 of the process:

```
jsonpRequest.prototype.getJsonp = function(){

    that.buildRequest();
    that.fetchJsonp();

    return that.listOfResults;

};
```

**The issue:**

Here is what I am calling after I define my JSON API class:

```
         var myJSON = json.getJsonp();

         console.log(myJSON);
```

Because it is asynchronous, it is moving on to the console log before the callback function is invoked, resulting in `MYJSON` to be `undefined`. I am not sure how I can daisy chain my code together in such a way where it runs the callback before moving on.

I tried to emulate the solution from [How can I get this JSONP call to return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465011/how-can-i-get-this-jsonp-call-to-return-a-value). I may be missing a step or I am perhaps ignorant of something! Any help to clarify this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :).

P.S. I would like to avoid using JQuery etc... It would be beneficial to keep this strictly as raw JavaScript.

Comment: In order to see the value of `myJSON` you'll have to wait until the server response comes back. Try testing with a `setTimeout`. You can't setup a variable with asynchronous data and immediately expect the result.

Comment: Hey there hitautodestruct, thanks for the suggestion :). I was aware of `setTimeout` being a possible solution. It's a perfectly valid solution. However, I was reluctant to do so after the points Relfor made in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465011/how-can-i-get-this-jsonp-call-to-return-a-value. Still, I could perhaps implement `setTimeout` as a fail safe for if the server is not responding :). Thanks!

Comment: Hey, just an FYI the setTimeout is not a good solution since you never know exactly how much time it will take the server to respond. I suggested it merely for testing purposes.

Comment: Hey, yeah that was my hang up with it too, thanks for suggesting it for testing purposes though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure how I can daisy chain my code together in such a way where it runs the callback before moving on.

You can’t do that. You must rely on callbacks. Add a `callback` parameter to your `jsonpRequest` constructor, and invoke that callback after you do `setListOfResults(data)`. You may also wish to allow for setting the `this` context in which the callback will be executed.

```
jsonpRequest.prototype.processCallback = function(data){

    alert(data);
    that.setListOfResults(data);
    that.callback.apply(that.context, [data]);

};
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense - I had an a-ha moment after I read it, it made the process make much better sense. I implemented the code, went to try it and the server seems to have gone down! Ha ha. I will check the code ASAP and I'll mark this as answered if it all works :)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks very much for helping me get the process in my head :).